# Malloc not allocating memory for char*

Tags: c, string, char, malloc

I'm getting a simple, unexpected result with malloc() and strings. 
The code:

```
int main(void) {

char* b64str;
char* binStr = "00000101";

printf("Expected size of allocated structure (b64str): 8\n");
b64str = (char*)malloc((strlen(binStr)+1)*sizeof(char));
printf("Actual size of allocated structure (b64str): %d\n\n", strlen(b64str));
```

The output:

```
Expected size of allocated structure (b64str): 8
Actual size of allocated structure (b64str): 0
```

Why?

Comment: Please provide the reason why you expect that value. Best with references to the documentation and the standard.

Comment: `b64str` points to freshly allocated memory, which might contain any values.  It happens that on your system, on that particular run, the memory contains a NUL character at the beginning.   You really shouldn't access memory before you store anything to it, and Valgrind would identify this error if you were to use it.

Answer (score 5):

You allocated space to `b64str`, but that space is uninitialized.  Attempting to call `strlen` on that buffer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In your particular case, the first byte happened to be set to 0, but you can't depend on that behavior.

You can't tell how much memory was allocated by looking at it.  You need to keep track of it yourself.

If you want to see whether or not the allocation failed, check if the returned pointer is `NULL`.

```
b64str = (char*)malloc((strlen(binStr)+1)*sizeof(char));
if (b64str == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`strlen()` reports the *length* of a *string*, not the amount of memory associated with an allocation.

> The `strlen` function returns the number of characters that precede the terminating null character.  C11dr §7.24.6.3 3

---

Consider an alteration to OP code.

```
char* binStr = "00000101";
printf("Result of strlen(binStr) %d\n", (int) strlen(binStr));
// Expect 8 to be printed.

char* b64str = (char*)malloc((strlen(binStr)+1)*sizeof(char));

strcpy(b64str, "123");
printf("Result of strlen(b64str) %d\n", (int) strlen(b64str));
// Expect 3 to be printed.

strcpy(b64str, "12345");
printf("Result of strlen(b64str) %d\n", (int) strlen(b64str));
// Expect 5 to be printed.
```

None of these printed the allocation size which was 9.  Note that the amount of allocated memory pointed to by `b64str` remains 9 even after a `strcpy(b64str, "123");`

```
size_t sz = strlen(binStr)+1)*sizeof(char);
printf("Allocation size %d\n", (int) sz);
// Expect 9 to be printed.
```

---

There is no standard way to determine the amount of memory associated with a non-`NULL` pointer that was returned from `malloc()`.

---

> `malloc` not allocating memory for `char*`  (OP)

Code did not check the return value of `malloc()` to know if the allocation succeeded.  Do a `NULL` check.  If code receives a non-`NULL`, allocation succeeded.  A return value of `NULL` is OK too when the size request is 0, but that is not an issue with `strlen(binStr)+1`.

> The malloc function returns either a null pointer or a pointer to the allocated space.  §7.22.3.4 2

```
char* b64str = malloc(strlen(binStr)+1);
if (b64str == NULL) {
  perror("OOM"); exit(-1);
}
```

---

Notes:

Cast not needed a `malloc()` return.
`sizeof(char)` is always 1.
Robust code checks allocation result

```
char* b64str = malloc(strlen(binStr)+1);
if (b64str == NULL) { perror("OOM"); exit(-1); }
```

Use `"%zu"` to match the type `size_t` returned from `strlen()`

```
printf("Result of strlen() %zu\n", strlen(b64str));
```

Answer (score 0):

`strlen()` searches for the NUL terminator in a string. It does *not* tell you the size of the buffer allocated for that string! (It is only by chance that your first byte is a zero; other runs could produce a different result.)

So you must store the size of the buffer yourself if that's what you want. And if you want to see if any memory at all was allocated, then check if `b64str` itself is `NULL`.